# package for calculating exponent of power law distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, packages, distributions

There are some packages to fitting power law to empirical date in "R", "matlab", "python" [Here](http://tuvalu.santafe.edu/~aaronc/powerlaws/) with maximum likelihood method [As it said here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1062).
Does it exist similar package in Mathematica?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Start here to see what statistics functionality is available:

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Statistics.html
- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ProbabilityAndStatistics.html

Fitting is done with [`EstimatedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EstimatedDistribution.html) or [`FindDistributionParameters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistributionParameters.html).  You want to fit a [`ParetoDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParetoDistribution.html) for continuous data or a [`ZipfDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ZipfDistribution.html) for discrete data.

There is no need for a separate package.

Comment: Also, [ParetoDistribution](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParetoDistribution.html) cross-references with  [PowerDistribution](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerDistribution.html)

Comment: @BobHanlon thanks, Instead of data (because of their huge size) I saved distribution of data : instead of {32,21,48,52,32,32,32,32,21,48,21} I have {{32,5},{21,3},{48,2},{52,1}} , the repetition of each data, How can find parameter of Power Distribution with maximum likelihood method of that?

Comment: @jackcilba You need `ParetoDistribtion` or `ZipfDistribution`, *but not PowerDistribution*, to do what is described in the paper you linked.  To choose a fitting method, read the documentation of `EstimatedDistribution` that I already linked, especially the `ParameterEstimator` option.  Be sure to check under "Details" when reading ay documentation page.

Comment: @jackcilba - for additional questions post a new question rather than asking in a comment.